# Scatter plot colorbar - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

I'm trying to show a color bar of my scatter plot but I'm keep getting the error:

> TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable

This is what I'm doing to plot:

```
# Just plotting the values of data that are nonzero 
x_data = numpy.nonzero(data)[0] # x coordinates
y_data = numpy.nonzero(data)[1] # y coordinates

# Mapping the values to RGBA colors
data = plt.cm.jet(data[x_data, y_data])

pts = plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, marker='s', color=data)

plt.colorbar(pts)
```

If I comment the line `plt.colorbar(pts)` I got the plot correctly, but I would like to plot the color bar too.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're passing in specific rgb values, so matplotlib can't construct a colormap, because it doesn't know how it relates to your original data.

Instead of mapping the values to RGB colors, let `scatter` handle that for you.

Instead of:

```
# Mapping the values to RGBA colors
data = plt.cm.jet(data[x_data, y_data])

pts = plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, marker='s', color=data)
```

Do:

```
pts = plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, marker='s', c=data[x_data, y_data])
```

(Just pass in to `c` what you were originally passing into `plt.cm.jet`.)

Then you'll be able to construct a colormap normally.  The specific error is telling you that the colors have been manually set, rather than set through `set_array` (which handles mapping an array of data values to RGB).

Comment: It worked. I just have one last question.. I have tried this using color=data[x_data, y_data], and I got the same error message. So, c != color? Thank you, @JoeKington. (:

Comment: No, `color` is an alias for `facecolors`.  (This is a bit confusing, but it's due to inheriting matlab's plotting api.) `c` is a carryover from the original matlab's scatter.  `scatter` is intended to be called as `scatter(x, y, c=z1, s=z1)` to simultaneously display 4 variables.  (Two positions, vary by color, and vary by size).  Behind the scenes, `color` calls `set_facecolors` and `c` calls `set_array` on the output collection. In the long run, it's probably a good idea to make `color` behave identically to `c` if a scalar array is passed in.

Comment: Huuum, understood. (: However, my colors get pretty different (and I got squares with white contours) from the other plot, even if I passe the argument cmap=plt.cm.jet.

Comment: @pceccon - Yep! That's because in your original example, the range of the data was being scaled between 0 and 1, while in my example, it's being scaled between the min and max of the data.  To make it identical to the original, use `cmin=0, cmax=1`.

Comment: Right! Glad you caught that!