# How can I customize and show a color bar for a scatter plot based on values of a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

I am attempting to plot a color bar to represent color-coded scatterplot dots based on conditional statements to which ranges of values within a pandas dataframe column are assigned specific colors. I am able to successfully create the plot, but I have not been able to get the color bar to show up on the plot. Below is some context of what I am doing to show where the issue arises.

```
        ws = []
        for i in ws_max['max_ws']:
                if i < 34:
                        color = 'lightblue'
                elif i >= 34 and i < 64:
                        color = 'green'
                elif i >= 64 and i < 83:
                        color = 'yellow'
                elif i >= 83 and i < 135:
                        color = 'orange'
                else:
                        color = 'r'
                ws.append(color)
        winds = plt.scatter(lon_mean['mean_lon'],lat_mean['mean_lat'],s=200,color=ws,edgecolors='k',zorder=3)
        plt.colorbar(winds)
```

When I run the code above I get this traceback: `TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable`, which I attempted to address using this link  [Scatter plot colorbar - Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833102/scatter-plot-colorbar-matplotlib) but I was unsuccessful.